# How to upload more than 100 videos/day on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, limit

We requested a YouTube API quota extension and it was approved today. In the developer console, we could see the limit is 3,000,000.

[image]

After uploading 100 videos, we can’t upload anymore. It shows

[image]

What could we do if we hope to upload more videos(like 500) in one day?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... it can be happen because of your size of the videos are too large. So the server is only allow you to upload upto certain extend of files in the moment

Comment: But I need to upload a large number of more than 100 videos for Google ads every day. Is there any good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

100 videos are the max per day a non-company youtube page can upload each 24 hours

> There's a limit to how many videos a channel can upload each day. If you get an error saying “Upload limit reached” when trying to upload a video, try again in 24 hours.
>
> Limits may vary by region or channel history. Copyright strikes may impact channel history eligibility. Community Guidelines strikes will affect how much you can upload.

*from the youtube help page "How many videos you can upload per day"
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57407#zippy=%2Chow-many-videos-you-can-upload-per-day*